# How to make curly braces auto indent in sh-mode

Tags: indentation, shell-mode, sh-mode

If typed in `sh-mode` the closing brace is not auto-indented:

```sh
function()
{
    }
```

If typed in `c-mode` the closing brace is auto-indented when inserted:

```sh
function()
{
}
```

The exact keystrokes are: `f u n c t i o n ( ) ENT { ENT }`.

How can I change this behavior to match `c-mode`?

Comment: In `c-mode` these auto-indented feature is completed by `c-electric-brace` (specifically, `c-cleanup-list`), I'm not sure whether this is easy to adapt in `sh-mode` but I am afraid not. I suggest to use `electric-pair-mode`, and when you press enter, the indent is correctly both `sh-mode` and `c-mode`.

Comment: Yes it does align if I `ENT` after, but that's an extra sequence I'd rather not do.